# Is there a way to send data to Logentries in a NodeJS + Browserify context?

Tags: node.js, browserify, aws-lambda, logentries, serverless-framework

I am trying to send data to Logentries from an AWS Lambda function, created using the JAWS Framework (which is now the [Serverless Framework](http://serverless.com/)), which uses Browserify as its default builder. However...

- The [logentries/le_node](https://github.com/logentries/le_node) package [doesn't seem to be compatible](https://github.com/logentries/le_node#le_node-logentries-client) with Browserify.
- The [logentries/le_js](https://github.com/logentries/le_js) package doesn't seem to work in a NodeJS environment (due to XMLHttpRequest being undefined).

Is there some way to send data to Logentries in this situation?

I looked briefly at connecting Logentries to AWS CloudWatch directly, but the option for enabling that (via Logentries) says "Enable Cloudwatch & infrastructure information", whereas I'm just looking for a way to feed specific CloudWatch streams into specific Logentries log sets, and I don't need any of the infrastructure information.

**EDIT:**
Based on feedback from Logentries support staff, I ended up using an HTTP POST API that they have (not to be confused with their deprecated HTTP PUT API). Here's the code I used:
https://github.com/silinternational/lambda-le-logger

Comment: Out of respect for those who edited this question (and/or approved the edit), I'll merely add this as a comment for the moment, not undo their edit. However, this question was specific to the jaws-framework, not to serverless. A significant refactor was done from JAWS to Serverless (it wasn't merely a rename). They require different versions of Node, among other things, which could change whether a proposed solution works. I have not yet made the change from jaws-framework to serverless, for what it's worth. Thank you, though, for trying to keep this up-to-date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`xmlhttprequest`](https://github.com/driverdan/node-XMLHttpRequest) to define a global `XMLHttpRequest` so you can use `le_js` in Node:

```
global.XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;
var LE = require('le_js');
...
```

Comment: For others who may try this approach: something about the process of browserifying my code and deploying it to AWS Lambda resulted in only the first call to Logentries working (per execution of the Lambda). I suspect it may be related to the way xmlhttprequest uses the file system internally, though I haven't verified that.